# Does Blackrock iShares know that I have bought their product?

Tags: stocks, etf, broker

Let's say I buy an iShares ETF, does Blackrock have this information or only my broker has this information? Is there a "customer service" or something that I can contact to ask a question? Are they supposed to have?

Comment: What problem are you having that your broker can't answer?

Comment: @RonJohn No problem for now, I just wanted to understand if the stock belongs really to me or if it belongs to me through a broker. When I buy a computer at a store I own the computer, the store has nothing to do after the buy. It seems as it is not the same thing in the stock market.

Comment: You don't own *a* stock, you've bought shares in a **fund** managed by Blackrock.

Comment: @RonJohn: Sure, but the same question obviously can apply to a share of a fund just as to a share of a stock.

Comment: @RonJohn OK, but do I really own these shares or not? Is the fact that I have bought the shares _written_ somewhere other than the broker?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the case of owning an ETF the parent company, in this case Blackrock, "has" a list of all the investors in that Exchange Traded Fund. In the case of an individual share of some stock the answer is also yes. There is an investor relations dept./officer who maintains a list of investors - which gets reconciled before a shareholder vote.

The brokerage have the most up-to-date list at any time and they update the listed exchange who can update the investor relations dept of Blackrock or the public company.

> OK, but do I really own these shares or not? Is the fact that I have bought the shares written somewhere other than the broker?

Yes you own the shares. Your broker is the *custodian*. You can physically take custody of the shares you own as paper shares if you request them from your broker - check your investor agreement / contract with your broker.

Comment: The broker may be holding them in "street name" and Blackrock may have no idea which customers that use the broker own shares.

Comment: Also worth adding most brokers who do this offer the ability to transfer to your name, albeit for a fee.